# cshtml file has no attached C# file

Tags: visual-studio, razor, razor-pages

I have a Razor page with the `.cshtml` file extension.

Register.cshtml

```
@using Project.Models.Auth
@model RegisterModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="register-form">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>

        <input type="text" asp-for="FirstName" placeholder="First name" id="first-name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="FirstName"></span>

        <input type="text" asp-for="LastName" placeholder="Last name" id="last-name" />
        <span asp-validation-for="LastName"></span>

        <input type="email" asp-for="Email" placeholder="Email" id="email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email"></span>

        <input type="password" asp-for="Password" placeholder="Password" id="password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>

        <label for="remember-me">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="RememberMe" id="remember-me" />
            Remember me
        </label>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>

        <p id="message"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Although the file has no attached `Register.cs` file which I need to add form validation code.
It appears there should be a button in the context menu which says "View code" or a children of the `Register.cshtml` file named `Register.cs`, but neither of them is present.

This happens in Visual Studio Community 2022.

Comment: ....are you familiar with ASP.NET MVC at all? "Code-behind" files simply don't exist - there is no need for a `Register.cs` file. (And where is `RegisterModel` defined? Where is the Controller Action?)

Comment: I'm talking about the separate c# file where you write code for a page

Comment: You're making a faulty assumption there...

Comment: Observe that your `Register.cshtml` has [a `@model` declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-8.0#strongly-typed-data-viewmodel) instead of a `@page` declaration, which means `Register.cshtml` is an MVC View File and not a _Razor Page_.

Comment: Ah, i got confused and didn't know about that. Thanks.